# Cannot convert value of type URL.Type to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: swift, server, nsurlconnection

I don't understand what went wrong over here,

// Now actually send the request to the server.

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as? URLRequest ?? URLRequest(url: URL), queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: {(_ response: URLResponse, _ data: Data, _ connectionError: Error?) -> Void in
        var resultText: String? = nil
        if connectionError != nil {
            resultText = "** ERROR = \(connectionError)"
            print("**Error  \(unsuccessLabel.text)")
            uploadPleaseWaitLabel.hidden = true
            //****** 12-17
            unsuccessLabel.hidden = false
            //****** 12-17
            sessionUploadedYorN = "N"
            self.useDocument()
        }
        else {
```

Comment: I'm getting the error of: Cannot convert value of type URL.Type to expected argument type 'URL'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
request as? URLRequest ?? URLRequest(url: URL)
```

You are attempting to create an `URLRequest` with the argument `URL`. Just pass there the real `URL` instance, not the type `URL`.

Possible solution:

```
let actualRequest = request as? URLRequest ?? URLRequest(url: URL(string:"http://www.google.com")!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(actualRequest,
                                        queue: OperationQueue.main,
                                        completionHandler:
    { (_ response: URLResponse, _ data: Data, _ connectionError: Error?) -> Void in
        var resultText: String? = nil
        if connectionError != nil {
            resultText = "** ERROR = \(connectionError)"
            print("**Error  \(unsuccessLabel.text)")
            uploadPleaseWaitLabel.hidden = true
            //****** 12-17
            unsuccessLabel.hidden = false
            //****** 12-17
            sessionUploadedYorN = "N"
            self.useDocument()
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As of Swift4, your code wouldn't compile even with that fix (there is a signature issue within the closure). More than that, `NSURLConnection` is deprecated since iOS9 and is discouraged to use.
You should refactor your code to use with Swift-native `URLSession` and its `dataTask` instance method. It does practically the same.